# Can you use R programming in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, r, google-bigquery

I am currently taking an online data analytics course and am told I will soon learn R. For my current assignment I was instructed to post a question in this forum. So I am curious to know if R is a language that is used in BigQuery or if it is used in a totally different program.

As I am not familiar with R language I have not tried to use it in BigQuery.

Comment: I don't know much about BigQuery, but I see it accepts standard ANSI SQL queries. There are a number of database packages in R that can communicate using SQL. It is possible that https://dept.stat.lsa.umich.edu/~jerrick/courses/stat701/notes/sql.html has some info for you.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/user-managed/use-r-bigquery  ?

Comment: Please go back to your instructor/professor and advise them that asking a question on StackOverflow as a homework assignment (without clear programming focus, example, goal, etc) is off-topic and counter to the netiquette and expected use of Stack. I've seen this before, and it is frustrating: your first resource for questions should be your teaching staff, not an online forum, and I feel it is irresponsible of them to (from appearances) shirk their responsibilities. Good luck with your course, please be mindful of how Stack wants to be used by (re)taking their [tour].

Comment: (We will do our best to help, certainly, but within reasonable bounds :-)